# Cannot find angular2-redux-starter.git

Tags: node.js, git, angular

this is more than likely pilot error, but I thought I would try.  If this is poor form, please tell me where I can learn good form.  I'm new to Angular.

I'm trying to start up my application from NPM.  It "was working fine", and then it wasn't.

The following is what was in the npm-debug.log:

```
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
19 error node v6.3.0
20 error npm  v3.10.8
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error angular2-redux-starter@0.2.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server -d --inline --progress --no-info`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the angular2-redux-starter@0.2.0 dev script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server -d --inline --progress --no-info'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-redux-starter package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server -d --inline --progress --no-info
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs angular2-redux-starter
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls angular2-redux-starter
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

In my package.json file I have the following:

```
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/rangle/angular2-redux-starter.git"
```

When I go to the url above it redirects to https://github.com/rangle/angular2-redux-example

I'm not sure if this is the reason I'm having the issue.  Are my references simply out of date? When you go to the new repo it says it's deprecated.  Can anyone suggest the best course of action here? Is this even the right place to post?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why not go for that repo instead ? https://github.com/ngrx/example-app

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided may not be the right one. As its showing *deprecated* in git. Have you tried this link https://github.com/rangle/angular2-redux-example/tree/archive. But if you want the latest one, use the actual repo as Ced mentioned.